# Unit test ParameterBindingValidationException

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, pester

Can somebody show me the best way to test non-nullable string parameters with Pester?

I receive a `ParameterBindingValidationException` when I pass an empty string my PowerShell module.

```
function Get-MyFunc {
  param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$stringParameter
  )

  ## rest of function logic here
}
```

I was expecting to be able to do this in my test:

```
Describe 'When calling Get-MyFunc with empty parameters' {
  It 'Should throw an exception' {
    Get-MyFunc '' | Should Throw
  }
}
```

Or this:

```
Describe 'When calling Get-MyFunc with empty parameters' {
  It 'Should throw an exception' {
    PesterThrow { Get-MyFunc '' } | Should Be $true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the check in a scriptblock:

```
Describe 'When calling Get-MyFunc with empty parameters' {
  It 'Should throw an exception' {
    { Get-MyFunc '' } | Should Throw
  }
}
```

See [Pester Wiki](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/Should#throw).

Comment: Thanks, couldn't see that for the world on Friday!